# How I type Arabic text without error boxes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, arabic

I want to use the Arabic text in Photoshop v22.0.1 but it only types in as error boxes. I have tried the Preferences > Type > World-Ready Layout. and Paragraph's World-Ready Layout with Middle Eastern Features, Single-line Composer but this does not seem to work. Please kindly help on how I can fix this to use the Arabic text in Photoshop. Thank you.

To be more specific, I found this kind of problem solving at photoshop 21.2 but it still having.

https://feedback.photoshop.com/conversations/photoshop/photoshop-212-arabic-text-issue/5f5f46234b561a3d4275a5ee

Also, In my case font is not problem. because it working at adobe XD.

Comment: Hi Welcome to GDSE. Errors/bugs should be reported to Adobe, or you should contact them directly for support if the fix you found is not working. Unfortunately tech support is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi, Billy Kerr. Thank for answering my question. I got it what you said. I'm gonna contact to Adobe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still monitoring this thread but I did a lot of typing in Arabic and Persian for a project in Photoshop and I had the same problem.

Nothing fixed it at all, except one thing: uninstalling Photoshop, going into creative Cloud > preferences > Apps> English (arabic script) see the screenshot.

Eventually, when I stopped working on the Arabic/Persian project I had to uninstall Photoshop and re-install Photoshop > English (international) because when you have it as English (Arabic script) everything is default set Right to left, all the Arabic Fonts are listed first, and I'm English speaking so it was not convenient for me. There is unfortunately no more elegant way to do it.

what I suggest is creating several documents when you're in the setting English (arabic script) because the text boxes inside your file will retain correct Arabic ligatures and properties.  IT's the same situation with Adobe Premiere. So I created my original Premiere projects with the English Arabic but I've reverted to English international and now I've made 57 videos that contain Arabic text, but they are all copies of the original template I created with the right settings, and everything has[image: English (Arabic setting)] been maintained.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!